# React component not updating mathjax formula unless its name starts with a lower case

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering, formula, mathjax

My React (^18.2.0) project contains several components.  All those components contain mathjax ([better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax)) formulas and text. When I update the text, it updates correctly in the browser.  When I update the mathjax formulas, I don't see any update in the browser unless the name of the function related to the components starts with a lowercase.

For example this component, (`SetTheory1.js`) updates the formula `R_{XY}` but when I change the name from `setThor1` to `SetThor1`, the formula doesn't update:

```
import { MathJax, MathJaxContext } from "better-react-mathjax";

const setThor1 = () => {
 
  return (
    <div className="ddd">
      <MathJaxContext>
        <MathJax inline>
        this is a formula \({"R_{XY}"} \)
        </MathJax>
      </MathJaxContext>
    </div>
  );
};

export default setThor1;
```

The text (`"this is a formula"`) updates correctly in both cases. Why!? I expect that the naming of the const exposing the component is just a convention and has no effect in updating the rendering  the component or not.
[image: project structure]

/*************************App.js*************************************/

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

//import { MathJax, MathJaxContext } from "better-react-mathjax";
import Header from "./templateComponents/Header";
import Side from "./templateComponents/Side";
import Footer from "./templateComponents/Footer";
import IntroToProbaAndStat from "./Components/Introduction to proba and stat";

import SetThe2 from  "./Components/setTheory2";
import SetTheo1 from  "./Components/SetTheory1";
import RandomExp from "./Components/randomExperiment";
import RandomVar1 from "./Components/randomVariable1";
import RandomVar2 from "./Components/randomVariable2";
import RandomVar3 from "./Components/randomVariable3";
import RandomVar4 from "./Components/randomVariable4";
import ExampleUseEffectC from "./Components/UseEffectExample";

import "./assets/css/StatStyle.css";

function Appk() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Side />
        <Footer />
        <div
          id="sec"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(245,244,240)" }}
          className="absolute p-4 max-sm:w-[30%] right-0 text-lg top-9 h-[90%] w-[70%] overflow-y-auto"
        >
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/IntrToProbaP">
              <IntroToProbaAndStat />
            </Route>

            <Route exact path="/setThe1P">
              <SetTheo1 />
            </Route>

            <Route exact path="/setThe2P">
              <SetThe2 />
            </Route>

 
            <Route exact path="/randomExpP">
              <RandomExp />
            </Route>
            
          
            
            <Route exact path="/randomVarP1">
              <RandomVar1 />
            </Route> 
            <Route exact path="/randomVarP2">
              <RandomVar2 />
            </Route> 
            <Route exact path="/randomVarP3">
              <RandomVar3 />
            </Route> 
            <Route exact path="/randomVarP4">
              <RandomVar4 />
            </Route> 
            
            <Route exact path="/ExampleUseEffect">
              <ExampleUseEffectC />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default Appk;
```

Comment: Does it work any better if you do `export default function SetThor1() { ... }`?

Comment: How do you import and use it? Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: thank you very much Daniel, the behaviour is exactly similar that is when I put  export default function SetThor1() { ... } (with S in SetThor1 capital case) it doesn't update the mathjax formula, but when I put export default function setThor1() { ... } (with s in setThor1 lower case) it updates the mathjax formula but in both cases it updates normal text

Comment: thank you ghybs for your reply I don't know how I can give more details except

Comment: How do you update the formula? Normally you update via state or props but the math comes from neither? Are you talking about hot reloading in the dev server when you change the source files?

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the solution it was a silly mistake, I included a space at the end of the mathjax formula.